# How to indentify the positions that a word occurs in a given text?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I am developing a program where you can input a sentence and then search for a word. The program will then tell you at which positions this word occurs. I have written some code but do not know how to continue.

```
Module Module1


Sub Main()
    Dim Sentence As String
    Dim SentenceLength As Integer
    Dim L As Integer = 0
    Dim LotsofText As String = Console.ReadLine


    Console.WriteLine("Enter your word ") : Sentence = Console.ReadLine


    For L = 1 To LotsofText.Length
        If (Mid(LotsofText, L, 1)) = " " Then
        End If
        L = L + 1


        Dim TextCounter As Integer = 0
        Dim MainWord As String = Sentence
        Dim CountChar As String = " "
        Do While InStr(MainWord, CountChar) > 0
            MainWord = Mid(MainWord, 1 + InStr(MainWord, CountChar), Len(MainWord))
            TextCounter = TextCounter + 1

            'Text = TextCounter + 2
            ' Console.WriteLine(Text)

        Loop


        Console.WriteLine(TextCounter)


        Console.Write("Press Enter to Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()


End Sub


End Module
```

Comment: Mid, Instr etc exist only for compatibility with VB6 and VBA. They should never be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find only words and not sub-strings (for example to ignore "cat" in "catty"):

```
    Dim LotsofText = "catty cat"
    Dim Sentence = "cat"

    Dim pattern = "\b" & Regex.Escape(Sentence) & "\b"
    Dim matches = Regex.Matches(LotsofText, pattern)

    For Each m As Match In matches
        Debug.Print(m.Index & "") ' 6
    Next
```

If you want to find sub-strings too, you can remove the `"\b"` parts.

Answer (score 1):

Transform this piece of code from C# to Visual Basic. `match.Index` will indicate the position of the given word.

```
var rx = new Regex("your");
foreach (Match match in rx.Matches("This is your text! This is your text!"))
{
    int i = match.Index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this function to your code:

```
Public Function GetIndexes(ByVal SearchWithinThis As String, ByVal SearchForThis As String) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim Result As New List(Of Integer)

    Dim i As Integer = SearchWithinThis.IndexOf(SearchForThis)

    While (i <> -1)
        Result.Add(i)
        i = SearchWithinThis.IndexOf(SearchForThis, i + 1)
    End While

    Return Result
End Function
```

And call the function in your code:

```
Dim Indexes as list(of Integer) = GetIndexes(LotsofText, Sentence)
```

Now GetIndexes will find all indexes of the word you are searching for within the sentence and put them in the list Indexes.